# onclick won't let me set div display to hidden and another to inline, inline works once when hidden commented out

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried searching this on Google and here but nothing like the issue I'm having is coming up so I am fairly certain this is not a duplicate topic.

I have 3 divs I'm trying to hide 2 and display one using JavaScript. It shouldn't be complicated as I've done it many times before but it's driving me insane.

Below is my div layout:

```
<div id="top_scorer">
   <span id="top_scores_menu">
      <a onclick='getTopPlayer("top_mens")'>Men's</a>
      <a onclick='getTopPlayer("top_womens_2nd")'>Women's 1st</a>
      <a onclick='getTopPlayer("top_womens_1st")'>Women's 2nd</a>
   </span>

   <div id="top_mens" class="topPlayer">
      <? echo $mens_top_scorers; ?>
   </div>
   <div id="top_womens_1st" class="topPlayer" style="display: none ;">
      <? echo $womens_1st_top_scorer; ?>
   </div>
   <div id="top_womens_2nd" class="topPlayer" style="display: none ;">
      <? echo $womens_2nd_top_scorer; ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is the simple JavaScript I am trying to use:

```
function getTopPlayer(WhoToShow){
    //alert(WhoToShow);
    document.getElementsByTagName('topPlayer').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById(WhoToShow).style.display='inline';

}
```

The weird thing is if I comment out everything within the function except for the alert, it works as expected all the time, if I comment out everything except the  `document.getElementById(WhoToShow).style.display='inline'` It works ONCE and then the links are unclickable, if I leave the `document.getElementById(WhoToShow).style.display='inline';` uncommented it doesn't work at all.

Now I have tried this many different ways, Originally I was trying to use the following:

```
function getTopPlayer(WhoToShow, hide1, hide2){
    document.getElementById(hide1).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(hide2).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(WhoToShow).style.display="inline";
}
```

This works perfectly on the first click then noting happens on any further onclick's. The only other thing I can think of that may be having an effect is that the php code simply echo's out a published google doc graph iframe, unless I have stupidly overlooked something ridicules.

This is an example of the google doc iframe script echo'ed by the php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js">
{
    "dataSourceUrl": "//docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AmOgECNc58wCdFJzUVkyMmJ1dTBqXzVuQmxlc3F0UkE&transpose=1&headers=1&range=A1%3AB100&gid=1&pub=1",
    "options": {
        "vAxes": {
            "1": {
                "useFormatFromData": true
            },
            "0": {
                "useFormatFromData": true
            }
        },
        "title": "Womens 2nd Team",
        "booleanRole": "certainty",
        "animation": {
            "duration": 0
        },
        "hAxis": {
            "title": "Number of Goals",
            "useFormatFromData": true,
            "viewWindowMode": "pretty",
            "viewWindow": {}
        },
        "isStacked": false,
        "width": 600,
        "height": 371
    },
    "state": {},
    "chartType": "BarChart",
    "chartName": "Chart 3"
}
```

I would really appreciate any Help or advice anyone can offer as I'm ready to take my frustration out on my laptop.

## Resolved (kinda)

so I was able to track down the source of the issue to the Google generated script, I replaced the interactive chart script with the Image chart and that works as expected, Unfortunately I could not get it to work with the interactive Charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `getElementsByTagName` instead of `getElementsByClassName`. And it returns an array of elements we need to loop through.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="top_scorer">
   <span id="top_scores_menu">
      <a href="#" onclick='getTopPlayer("top_mens");return false;'>Men's</a>
      <a href="#" onclick='getTopPlayer("top_womens_1st");return false;'>Women's 1st</a>
      <a href="#" onclick='getTopPlayer("top_womens_2nd");return false;'>Women's 2nd</a>
   </span>

   <div id="top_mens" class="topPlayer">
      mens top
   </div>
   <div id="top_womens_1st" class="topPlayer" style="display: none ;">
      womens 1st
   </div>
   <div id="top_womens_2nd" class="topPlayer" style="display: none ;">
     womens 2nd
   </div>
</div>​
```

**Javascript**

```js
var getTopPlayer = function(WhoToShow){
    var tp = document.getElementsByClassName('topPlayer');
    for(var i = 0; i < tp.length; i++){
        tp[i].style.display='none'
    }
    document.getElementById(WhoToShow).style.display='block';
}​
```

**UPDATE**

I got the info that getElementsByClassName does not work in IE < 9 in a simular answer I did so I added some code on that answer that might help this one aswell.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12386152/600101

Comment: Edited the script just a tad and removed `wts` since it was a remnant of debug.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Henrik but That didn't have any effect at all I'm afraid, Could I ask what the purpose of the return false is and why you assigned the function to a var rather then just call it?

Comment: That code worked as a charm for me in the above scenario, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fe5AK/). If it works there but not in your code you have other issues in your code. Like the chart javascript that you output from PHP. You first call the `.js` file and in the same `<script>` block starts out with a `{`. No function call or nothing. Regarding the `return false`, I noted that the `<a>` tag wasn't using `href` and was therefor invalid. So added `#` but then the `onclick` needs to `return false` not to call the `href`. And regarding `var getTopPlayer = function` it's more a preference.

Comment: So I have come to the conclusion that it is some issue with the google script. I did not write this as it was generated by google spread sheets. I could not resolve it with the interactive chart so I just used the Image version and it works fine. as for the `{'s` I have never seed or used any js script like it before so I didn't get it either. Thanks for the Help Henrik

Comment: You're welcome and glad you also found a solution with the image version. Good luck on the project!

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED ANSWER! Rename the divs with numbers, then cycle through them with a loop, only showing the selected one.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/Ysaer/

Comment: I tried that kha0s and while it works fine with the <p>'s you created it does not seem to want to work with the Google doc's script so I think it must be some issue with that

Comment: Hmm...Do you have a link to where this is hosted?

Comment: unforunitly not as I am currently running it on local machine at home, but I will try to upload it tomorrow and post a Link

Comment: Sorry, but I'll be gone tommorow...so i'll see what I can do in the next few minutes...

Comment: Thanks Kha0s, turns out the issue is with the Google interactive chart script, I replaced it with the static Image alternative and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('topPlayer').style.display='none';
```

This does... NOTHING. `topPlayer` is not a "TagName" is it?

Comment: your right, my bad, was one of the suggested "solutions" I got from Googling and it being late and me Tired I never realised,Thanks for the suggestion Unfortunately that wasn't the (only) issue as I mention I had tried other ways.